# can I use this code instead of malloc function, because it seems to be working same for dynamic memory allocation in C language

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am learning about dynamic memory allocation c language,I found bellow code that uses malloc function,but can I use the code at last for same purpose without using malloc function.both codes give same output

//code that uses malloc function

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>
int main(){
    int *ptr;
    int n,sum=0;
    printf("Enter the size of array \n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    ptr=(int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    if (ptr==NULL)
    {
        printf("Memory not allocated \n");
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {    
            printf("Enter element at %d position \n",i+1);
            scanf("%d",(ptr+i));
            sum=sum+(*(ptr+i));
        }
        printf("sum = %d",sum);
    }
}
```

//code that does not uses malloc function

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int n,sum=0;
    printf("Enter the size of array \n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int a[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {    
        printf("Enter element at %d position \n",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
        sum=sum+a[i];
    }
    printf("sum = %d",sum);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Sure, you can use the second code. Assuming the size fits in a stack frame, you're fine, since you're not returning a pointer to memory. Snippet #1 leaks memory, BTW, you should call `free(ptr)` (and consider using more descriptive variable names than `ptr`).

Comment: What if a user passes `n` that would require an array that exceeds the stack size? You should either check `n`'s value or allocate the array on the heap, i.e. use `malloc`

Comment: I suggest being aware that "variable length arrays" are not supported by some very common compilers

Answer (score 2):

If your user inputs a large number, the VLA (=variable-length-array) approach risks a stack overflow.

You can fight that by limiting the size, resorting to `malloc` if the users requests too large a value, but implementing such a dual allocation strategy seems like an unnecessary complication in this case.

It's simpler just to `malloc`.

---

Example of limiting the VLA size:

```
....
enum { MAX_CNT = 128 };
int a[n <= MAX_CNT ? n : 1];
int *ptr = a <= MAX_CNT ? &a[0] : malloc(int[n]);
if(!ptr){ printf("Memory not allocated \n"); return -1; }
//...
//...
if (a!=ptr) free(ptr);
```

The VLA approach has the benefits of being somewhat faster than `malloc` and of having better cache locality (these shouldn't matter much in the program you've shown).

On the other hand, the VLA feature isn't a mandatory part of C, which means not all conforming implementations need to support it.

Answer (score 0):

After trying to see why your code works, on more careful examination I can see that you populate the array and immediately reuse the value. So, you don't care if it gets corrupted. In fact, you don't need the array at all. The code below will work as well without even pretending to use the array.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int n,sum=0;
    printf("Enter the size of array \n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {    
        printf("Enter element at %d position \n",i+1);
        int v;
        scanf("%d",&v);
        sum=sum+v;
    }
    printf("sum = %d",sum);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

For pointers that last the lifetime of a program, you generally want to use `malloc`/`free`, however in this case it doesn’t really matter since you’re doing all the work in the `main` function. Both of those code samples do the same thing and produce the same result.

Edited to remove an incorrect statement regarding arrays in C.

Comment: "Arrays in C are just dynamically allocated pointers anyway." Uhm no.